# Testing for Cursor Not Found Error in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, cursor, mongoid

When I was processing large number of data I ended up in **Cursor Not Found Error** in Mongoid. And I googled and came across the below link:

[DBCursor mongodb](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html)

Now I'm using skip and limit function to process 100 data at once and continue till it reaches 7350, which is the count of my documents.

As it takes too long to produce Cursor Not Found Error. I wonder if there is any quick way I can test for occurrence of this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of mongoid and (mongo or moped) are you using?  From http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/ By default, the server will automatically close the cursor after 10 minutes of inactivity ...

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19987687 basically adding a `.no_timeout` when fetching objects like `FbCheckin.where(...).no_timeout.each`

Answer (score 0):

maybe [killOp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/) would work, i guess.