# Mongo query using mongoid in rails app causing cursor timeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongo query in my rails app that is timing out because the collection is huge.

```
FbCheckin.where(ext_fb_place_id: self.ext_fb_place_id).all
```

I've read from documentation that you can add a `timeout` option to prevent the cursor from timing out with the following message:

```
Moped::Errors::CursorNotFound: The operation: "GET MORE" failed with error
```

I've tried several ways including

```
FbCheckin.where(ext_fb_place_id: ext_fb_place_id, {:timeout=>false}).all
```

and

```
FbCheckin.find(ext_fb_place_id: ext_fb_place_id, {:timeout=>false}).all
```

but none of these prevent the cursor from timing out.

Does anyone know how I can make this query and gather all the `FbCheckins` without the cursor timing out beforehand?

Thanks

Comment: This [discussion on the mongoid mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongoid/9QxJZg9sSZo/discussion) could provide some helpful hints.

Comment: @cortex No, I simply just wrote a loop to pull batches at a time.

Answer (score 32):

What you want is to set the cursor timeout to false when you are querying mongodb.

Here is what you can do with mongoid 3:

```
FbCheckin.where(...).no_timeout.each do |fb_checkin|
  "do something with fb_checkin"
end
```

Comment: I had the same problem as @Huy. In a background task I iterate Object.all while updating the db. The update comes from mining web data and so it has a fetch delay in each loop to avoid too frequent remote page fetches. This caused the cursor to timeout. @Quentin's solution solved the problem. I changed my code to ```Object.all.no_timeout.each do |object|``` and it's running merrily along.

Answer (score 2):

Use **'no_cursor_timeout'** option along with the find query while using Mongo Ruby Driver.

This will disable all cursor timeouts. By default MongoDB tries to kill all cursors which have been inactive for more than 10 mins.

More info can be found [here](https://itisatechiesworld.wordpress.com/2017/02/23/mongoerroroperationfailure-cursor-not-found/).

Answer (score -3):

mongoid will kill long time query by default and then raise this error

you can change raise_not_found_error option in mongoid.yml to avoid this error

for example:

```
production:
  sessions:
   default:
     database: local
     hosts:
      - localhost:27017
     options:
       allow_dynamic_fields: true
       raise_not_found_error: false
```

Comment: "raise_not_found_error(true): Will raise a Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound when attempting to find a document by an id that doesnt exist. When set to false will only return nil for the same query."