# Mongoid - Cursor not found errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am randomly, but regularly, running into errors like this in my application.

> An exception occurred: 'Cursor not found, cursor id: 46772737523145 (43)' on '/var/www/mysite-prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/operation/result.rb:256:in `validate!''

It seems to be triggered by map reduce tasks

```
@collection.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(replace: 'mr-results').each do |res|
    some_var[res['_id']] = Integer(res['value'])
end
```

Any idea what might be the cause ?

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19987687 basically adding a `.no_timeout` when fetching objects like `FbCheckin.where(...).no_timeout.each`

Comment: Hey @Miguelgraz I still haven't found the proper way to call no cursor timeout with mapreduce (cf code above)